# Working 'gnu-screen' alternative for Minecraft Servers on WSL

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, minecraft, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to launch my minecraft server on SSH on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on Windows.

The way I plan to do it with a phone or something: Connect to vpn, then ssh into windows, then type wsl (works fine), and finally open a session (for example screen) and launch the script for the minecraft server in there.

The problem is, when I finally get into launching the script and detaching the screen and close the ssh connection, the screen will close after some time automatically.
WSL says it was terminated. I dont know what to do.

I should also add that the script should run permanently.
The mc server is running on java and constantly gives output. So I want it to be available all the time.

Comment: The Minecraft server supports Windows natively. Why are you trying to run it in WSL?

Comment: To control it via ssh all the time, I would use the build in RCON console but this is not supported in 1.5.2 (the only version a specific modpack is available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linuxgsm.com is a Server manager that is also available for minecraft, it uses tmux and is a perfect alternative with many other features.